Why Does Disabling UEFI Mode Warn Could Render System Unbootable
I can't launch virtual box on my Dell vostro 14 with Ubuntu 22.04.
The error message says the problem maybe secure boot. I disabled it, and under it was an option to disable UEFI. I clicked it by accident, and got a warning that disabling UEFI could render the system unbootable.
Why? And isn't it always possible to boot from a OS USB like Ubuntu if the OS is totally corrupted?

Sorry as written this question makes no sense.  This sentence especially from you question, (Why? And isn't it always possible to boot from a OS USB like Ubuntu if the OS is totally corrupted?)
